# File path inside braces

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

a quick question I hope.

I am using Joomla! 2.5.8. I have just discovered eCSSential and it uses the following code in the index.php

```
    <script>
    <!-- Add eCSSential.min.js inline here -->

    eCSSential({
        "all": "css/all.css",
        "(min-width: 20em)": "css/min-20em.css",
        "(min-width: 37.5em)": "css/min-37.5em.css",
        "(min-width: 50em)": "css/min-50em.css",
        "(min-width: 62.5em)": "css/min-62.5em.css"
    });
 </script>
```

now, in my Joomla! file I have this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template?>/js/eCSSential.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-1024.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-758.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 524px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-524.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/css/lightbox.css"  type="text/css" />
```

I can't quite see how I should write the file path in the braces in the script so it works in Joomla!. The example used is just a normal directory structure I guess? I've tried a few combinations but nothing works as the site remains un styled...

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Why use a dynamic template directory? As long as you're not switching, simply write the template name instead of

`<?php echo $this->template?>`.

Comment: Hi, I tried that replacing `<?php echo $this->template?>` with the template name but it still doesn't work. I must be missing something... `"all": "css/all.css",` would become... `"style": "<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/style.css",` But that's not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, some minor tweaks made:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/js/eCSSential.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-1024.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-758.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 524px)" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/nameoftemplate/css/max-width-524.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/lightbox.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your template folder name is correct.

then you can access it via following methods.

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

or

<link href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

or

<link href="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>templates/name of the template_folder/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in this case you will correct result otherwise the index.php rendering has some issue.
Check with default template and make sure its working fine.

Comment: Putting any of these in place of the ones below does not work...

`eCSSential({
        "all": "css/all.css",
        "(min-width: 20em)": "css/min-20em.css",
        "(min-width: 37.5em)": "css/min-37.5em.css",
        "(min-width: 50em)": "css/min-50em.css",
        "(min-width: 62.5em)": "css/min-62.5em.css"
    });
    </script>`